# Can't integrate with Algolia DocSearch

Tags: algolia, docusaurus

I try to integrate with Algolia DocSearch and it doesn't work.
I followed exactly the steps listed here: https://docusaurus.io/docs/search#using-algolia-docsearch but notwhing happend for more then a month.

- I created an Algolia account.
- Created the Algolia configuration in my site as written in the docs.
- Apply my site (for the crawler).
- Bought the premium plan so I can create other crawler (but the crawler interface not recognize my App key!).
  also, when I try to enter to the crawler admin I'm always got:
  "Your Algolia plan does not allow you to access the Crawler.

What did I miss?

Comment: Hi Bokris, the Algolia DocSearch program is specific to documentation and blogs for open-source software. If you are approved for the program, the DocSearch team will work with you to configure a crawler and index for your site. 

Outside of DocSearch, the Crawler is currently an additional charge, so you'd need to get that added to your account if you wanted to crawl your site yourself.